# Is it possible to disable Spring's @Async during unit test?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I have a method annotated with `@Async` say

```
@Async
public void makeFood() {}
```

but I'm just trying to test the logic of that method. Is it possible to test it synchronously?

Comment: Is there any requirements that you have a Spring `ApplicationContext` running?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, as long as your configuration does not have `@EnableAsync`, the method will be executed synchronously.