# JUnit-testing a Spring @Async void service method

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-async

I have a Spring service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SomeService {

    @Async
    public void asyncMethod(Foo foo) {
        // processing takes significant time
    }
}
```

And I have an integration test for this `SomeService`:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@Transactional
public class SomeServiceIntTest {

    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;

        @Test
        public void testAsyncMethod() {

            Foo testData = prepareTestData();

            someService.asyncMethod(testData);

            verifyResults();
        }

        // verifyResult() with assertions, etc.
}
```

Here is the problem:

- as `SomeService.asyncMethod(..)` is annotated with `@Async` and
- as the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` adheres to the `@Async` semantics

the `testAsyncMethod` thread will fork the call `someService.asyncMethod(testData)` into its own worker thread, then directly continue executing `verifyResults()`, possibly before the previous worker thread has finished its work.

How can I wait for `someService.asyncMethod(testData)`'s completion before verifying the results? Notice that the solutions to *[How do I write a unit test to verify async behavior using Spring 4 and annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20807232/923560)* don't apply here, as `someService.asyncMethod(testData)` returns `void`, not a `Future<?>`.

Comment: the nice solution [How do I write..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20807232/923560) you mention above is a practicable one, expose *asyncMethod* result type as *Future<Void>*, and return **new  AsyncResult<>(null);** at the last of *asyncMethod*; and in the test method, get the future from *asyncMethod* and wait for it, as like ```Future<Void> f = someService.asyncMethod(testData); f.get(); verifyResults();```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For `@Async` semantics to be adhered, [some active `@Configuration` class will have the `@EnableAsync` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29930166/923560), e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

  //

}
```

To resolve my issue, I introduced a new Spring profile `non-async`.

If the `non-async` profile is **not** active, the `AsyncConfiguration` is used:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@Profile("!non-async")
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

  // this configuration will be active as long as profile "non-async" is not (!) active

}
```

If the non-async profile **is** active, the `NonAsyncConfiguration` is used:

```
@Configuration
// notice the missing @EnableAsync annotation
@EnableScheduling
@Profile("non-async")
public class NonAsyncConfiguration {

  // this configuration will be active as long as profile "non-async" is active

}
```

Now in the problematic JUnit test class, I explicitly activate the "non-async" profile in order to mutually exclude the async behavior:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@Transactional
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "non-async")
public class SomeServiceIntTest {

    @Inject
    private SomeService someService;

        @Test
        public void testAsyncMethod() {

            Foo testData = prepareTestData();

            someService.asyncMethod(testData);

            verifyResults();
        }

        // verifyResult() with assertions, etc.
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but this only works if none of the spring configurations depend on a task executor. If the async tests are an issue I would suggest moving them to a separate surefire execution

Answer (score 27):

If you are using Mockito (directly or via Spring testing support `@MockBean`), it has a verification mode with a timeout exactly for this case:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22

```
someAsyncCall();
verify(mock, timeout(100)).someMethod();
```

Much more capable is the great library [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/), which has many options how to handle async assertions. Example:

```
someAsyncCall();
await().atMost(5, SECONDS)
  .untilAsserted(() -> assertThat(userRepo.size()).isEqualTo(1));
```

Comment: I used both of these answers.  Worked great!  Which I was nervous about because my test actually kicks off multiple async method calls.

Answer (score 26):

I have done by injecting 
**ThreadPoolTaskExecutor**

and then

**executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);**

before verifying results,
it as below:

```
  @Autowired
  private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    @Test
    public void testAsyncMethod() {

        Foo testData = prepareTestData();

        someService.asyncMethod(testData);

        executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        verifyResults();
    }
```

Comment: if you have more than one test in the same spring context, then you have to take care about restarting your executor, right?

Comment: Matthias, probably yes, but I can't remember and can't check it as I already changed my job :(

Comment: This worked, but slowed down my tests waiting for the timeouts.  So I have 5 tests, so the tests ran >5secs, which is really slow in testing world.  So I'm treating this as a backup solution.

Answer (score 5):

In case your method returns `CompletableFuture` use `join` method - [documentation CompletableFuture::join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--).

This method waits for the async method to finish and returns the result. Any encountered exception is rethrown in the main thread.

Comment: alternatively you can use CompletableFuture::get

Comment: Apparently if you are using Spring Boot, using CompletableFuture or Runnable spins off your own threads which can mess with Spring Boots threads.  So from my understanding, @Async uses Spring Boot for the threads which then is safe.  

If this is correct, then I'm kinda annoyed that Spring is so invasive that I am forced to use Spring solutions over vanilla Java solutions.

Comment: @cody.tv.weber You can specify your own executor, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61292577/3255540

Comment: Sure, and thank you for showing me this,  Still, I would rather be able to use pure Java if I wanted to.  Also, what is gonna happen whenever VirtualThreads come?  Am I gonna have to use a Spring version for that as well?  Not that big of a deal.  Just annoying.

Answer (score 3):

Just to extend the answer by @bastiat, which in my opinion should be considered the correct one, you should also specified the `TaskExecutor`, if you are working with multiple executors. So you would need to inject the correct one that you wish to wait for. So, let's imagine we have the following **configuration** class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Bean("myTaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor myTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(15);
        executor.setCoreCapacity(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MyTaskExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    // Everything else

}
```

Then, you would have a service that would look like the following one.

```
@Service
public class SomeServiceImplementation {

    @Async("myTaskExecutor")
    public void asyncMethod() {
         // Do something
    }

    // Everything else

}
```

Now, extending on @bastiat answer, the test would look like the following one.

```
@Autowired
private SomeService someService;

@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myTaskExecutor;

@Test
public void testAsyncMethod() {

    Foo testData = prepareTestData();

    this.someService.asyncMethod(testData);

    this.myTaskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    this.verifyResults();

    // Everything else
}
```

Also, I have a minor recommendation that has nothing to do with the question. I wouldn't add the `@Transactional` annotation to a **service**, only to the **DAO/repository**. Unless you need to add it to a specific service method that must be **atomic**.

Answer (score 0):

Just addition to the above solutions:

```
 @Autowired
  private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool;

    @Test
    public void testAsyncMethod() {
        // call async method
        someService.asyncMethod(testData);

        boolean awaitTermination = pool.getThreadPoolExecutor().awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertThat(awaitTermination).isFalse();

        // verify results
    }
```