# Testing Spring's @Async void-returning methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-async

I have a little problem with `@Async` methods that return `void` (or `Unit`, I'm writing in Kotlin) in my Spring app.

I don't know why, but when `@Async` method returns `void` it just doesn't execute, or at least it doesn't do what it is supposed to. Need to say, that in my async methods, I want to send an email using the `JavaMailSender`, so no big deal. Here is the method:

```
@Async
override fun sendEmail(locale: Locale, subject: String, message: String, to: String) {

    val msg = sender.createMimeMessage()
    println("1")
    val helper = MimeMessageHelper(msg, true, "utf-8")
    helper.setFrom("email@example.com")
    helper.setTo(to)
    println("2")
    helper.setSubject(getSubject(locale, null))
    println("3")
    helper.setText(processTemplate(locale, null, null), true)
    println("4")
    sender.send(msg)
    println("5")
}
```

But an email never comes, there is no exception logged (I am running a testNG test).

When I change the signature of the function to make it return `Future<String>` and add some dummy return line to the end of the function and then I call `service.sendEmail(...).get()`, the method's body magically executes and the email arrives.

In my `@Configuration` class, there is `@EnableAsync`. I also implemented `AsyncConfigurer` and provided own executor and exception handler, because I thought it could have been something with my executor bean definition, but nothing helps.

This is driving me crazy, because I just want to silently execute something in the background and it doesn't work. By silently I mean that I don't want to be bothered by exceptions thrown inside.

Do you have any ideas?

**Update:**
So as @pleft advised, I put some prints inside my method.
Now, when I run `mvn clean test`, I can see that 1,2,3 are printed, **but** not each time. Sometimes just 1 and 2 got printed. I also put print in my `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`, but that one is not called.
It looks like the background thread is being killed too soon or something.

**Update 2:**

My ServiceConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan
class ServiceConfig : ApplicationContextAware, EnvironmentAware, AsyncConfigurer {
    override fun getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler(): AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
        return AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler { ex, method, params ->
            println("Exception thrown")
        }
    }

    override fun getAsyncExecutor(): Executor {
        val executor = ThreadPoolTaskExecutor()
        executor.corePoolSize = 2
        executor.maxPoolSize = 2
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500)
        executor.threadNamePrefix = "asyncThread"
        executor.initialize()
        return executor
    }
}
/// other beans definitions..
```

Maybe it is important, maybe not, but I'm using Thymeleaf in that `processTemplate` method.

Comment: Are you sure it is not running with void return type? How about placing a `System.out.println("sending email");` line inside your `sendEmail` method and call this async method. Does it get printed in the console?

Comment: Well I suppose this means that an exception happens after step "2" or "3" which breaks the execution of the method. Can you post more classes of your spring setup e.g. the implementation of the `AsyncConfigurer` and yours `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler `?

Comment: @pleft Added the Config class. My other idea is, whether this is not cause by the fact that I am running this within a test, so when the Async method returns, the test ends (and as it is the only test I am running, it destroys the Context and all threads with it, what do you think about this?

Comment: Yeap I think it is this the reason, unit test completes while the new async thread is not yet completed. Here you can find something relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438862/junit-testing-a-spring-async-void-service-method

Comment: Yes! that is exactly what I found after I made it work by putting some Thread.sleep in my test. Anyway, thanks for ideas :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comment and my own observation (like putting some sleep in the test method) I found out the reason. This was cause by the destroying of the Spring Context inside the test. Because I had only one test running this async method, so the scenario was that the async method returned immediately and so did the test method. As it was the last (and only) method in my test suite, the testing Context was destroyed (and also all threads it created).

So the resolution is to either put sleeps in the tests (very ugly) or have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438862/junit-testing-a-spring-async-void-service-method) and get inspired.