# Writing an integration test for a service

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, wiremock

I have a service class that I would like to perform the integration test (whitebox). The method code,

```
   @Async( ELLA_THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR_NAME )
    public void invokeEllaAsync( final IrisBo irisBo ) {

        if( isTrafficAllowed( irisBo ) ) {
            callEllaService( irisBo );
        }
    }

    public void callEllaService( final IrisBo irisBo ) {

        HttpHeaders ellaHeaders = createRequestHeaders( irisBo );

        ServiceResponse<EllaResponseDto> response = connector.call( EllaDtoConverter.convertToRequest( irisBo ), ellaHeaders );

        if( !response.isSuccess() ) {
            LOG.error( "ERROR", response, irisBo );
        }
    }
```

The method that test is provided below,

```
@Test
public void testCallEllaServiceIsSuccessful() throws IOException {

    String emailAgeResponseJson = readFile( ELLA_RESPONSE_FILE );

    wireMockRule.stubFor( post( urlEqualTo( ELLA_ENDPOINT ) ).willReturn( okJson( emailAgeResponseJson ) ) );

    TestRequestInformation testRequestInformation = new TestRequestInformation();
    IrisBo irisBo = EllaTestDataProvider.createValidIrisBoWithoutRequest();


    service.callEllaService( irisBo );


}
```

I would like to validate the response data, The method `invokeEllaAsync` returns `void`. The response is inside the method `callEllaService`.

How do I validate the response data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a quick googling reveals [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438862/junit-testing-a-spring-async-void-service-method). Since I'm not 100% you're talking about Spring indeed, I don't suggest to consider this as a duplication.

Now I'll provide a couple of additional techniques, assuming we're talking about Spring's Async methods (the integration test is probably run with `SpringRunner`)

To start from the basics, in a nutshell, `@Async` methods are executed on the different thread pool. Technically it's done by generating a runtime proxy.
So there are many techniques (out of my head, since I didn't really use them) that could help:

**Option 1**

Disable an Async Support for tests. This can be done by creating some kind of condition on your custom configuration class that will enable async support. Something like this:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAsync
 @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "async.support.enabled", havingValue = true)
 public class MyAsyncEnablerConfiguration {

 }
```

For tests make the variable `false`

**Option 2**

If its a method on a controller and you use mockMvc testing (again, only my speculation, I don't know where the code really is), you can take advantage of `asyncDispatch` method that will take care of asynchronous requests.

It looks like this:

```
mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult)) // <-- Note this call
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                ...
```

A full example can be found [Here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/test-async-controller-mockmvc/)

**Option 3**

Note that the return type of `@Async` method doesn't have to be `void`. It can be `Future` or even spring's `AsyncResult`.
So if its a future - you could call `future.get()` in the code and get the result.

To read about the return result types more check [This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know an example with the `Wiremock` ?

Comment: No, sorry, but since Wiremock is used to mock the external service call which is by itself is not async or something, I don't think its relevant here as long as you don't want to verify that mock call.

Comment: I have a question. Do I need to keep enable async support for the config file with the LOC ` @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "async.support.enabled", havingValue = true)` and in the test file ` @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "async.support.enabled", havingValue = false)` ?